# HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest maximum length

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 application which is, internally, using a very long link with

```
Server.TransferRequest(url, true);
```

The URL is about 180,000 characters long. The user's address bar never sees it, but it is used internally later on.

However, this long URL ends up causing an `ArgumentException`, specifically:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
ThrowExceptionForHRInternal
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
Void ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Web.Util.Misc.ThrowIfFailedHr(Int32 hresult)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ScheduleExecuteUrl(String url, String queryString, String method, Boolean preserveForm, Byte[] entity, NameValueCollection headers, Boolean preserveUser)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest(String path, Boolean preserveForm, String method, NameValueCollection headers, Boolean preserveUser)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.TransferRequest(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
```

There appears to be no documentation on MSDN about this exception being thrown, nor can I find a way to increase the length. I've tried to modify, in Web.Config, these 2 options to no avail:

```
<requestLimits maxUrl="2097151" maxQueryString="2097151" />
<httpRuntime maxUrlLength="2097151" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

This is for an internal web application, so attack by URL length vector is not a large concern.

Does anyone know how I can avoid this problem?

**UPDATE**

I modified the code to remove the long query string portion and put it in a header instead, and use a call like:

```
Server.TransferRequest(url, true, this.Request.HttpMethod, this.Request.Headers);
```

Where the headers now have the very long query string in it. The exception changed to:

```
Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation.
 (System.ArithmeticException)

ThrowExceptionForHRInternal
mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
Void ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32, IntPtr)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at System.Web.Util.Misc.ThrowIfFailedHr(Int32 hresult)
   at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ScheduleExecuteUrl(String url, String queryString, String method, Boolean preserveForm, Byte[] entity, NameValueCollection headers, Boolean preserveUser)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.TransferRequest(String path, Boolean preserveForm, String method, NameValueCollection headers, Boolean preserveUser)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.TransferRequest(String path, Boolean preserveForm, String method, NameValueCollection headers)
```

Comment: This seems more like the value for.one of your parameters is too large for the data type that is accepting it. Like int a = 99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

Comment: If that's the case, that is sad.